# Shared Persistent Storage in Python

Tags: python, multiprocess

Several processes are each writing a file to a directory. The goal is to control the size of the directory such that whenever it reaches a size (S), all processes stop writing to the directory and discard the file they are about to write.

If the size then becomes lower than S because some of those files were removed, the processes will resume writing files.

It seems that I need inter-process locking to achieve this design. However, I thought maybe there's an easier way, since inter process locking is not readily available in python and obviously there's contention between processes.

Python 2.7
Platforms (Win, Mac, Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lock files may be an option. For example, each process checks for a file like "/target_dir/lock" before write. If file exists, process will not write anything. So you have to run separate monitor process, which checks directory size, and creates or deletes lock file.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of having a monitor process. Without a monitor process, each process needs to update a size written in a file as it adds another file (or removes). It creates a lot of contention, but doesn't have a monitor.

Comment: You can add checks in your writer processes. So each process before write check the dir size. If it reaches some threshold, process will create lock file and stop writing. If it doesn't reach one but lock file exists, process will delete lock file and start writing. IMHO, it is possible but unclean solution, separate monitoring process would be better.

Comment: Checking dir size can be very expensive on each write. On Windows, you literally have to enumerate each file and add up the sizes.